# How to enable guest user & multiple user mode

Tags: rom, multi-user

I have an old Amazon Kindle Fire tablet (Tate) and have installed a custom Android Rom on it.

Most of the Kitkat Roms allow for guest user mode and multiple accounts (where multiple people can have their own account on the tablet).

However, this functions seems disabled in any ROM that is later than KitKat.

I have tried editing the build prop file to re-enable this functionality ([as discussed here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/guide-enabling-multi-user-lollipop-t3064326)). But all that does is just put a shortcut to the "contacts" app where the guest/user switcher is supposed to be.

Is there anyway I can enable guest user & multiple user mode. I was under the impression that this functionality is built into Android.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-user function is built into Android since KitKat 4.4, but as an optional feature, ROM developers may opt in to remove it thoroughly rather than simply disabling it.

Comment: I am guessing there is no way to 'un-remove' it?

Comment: Not easily. It might be easier to simply flash a custom ROM that has not been crippled.

Comment: @m-p-3 Is there anyway to find such a rom for Amazon Tate. I've tried several, but none of them have this feature.

Comment: @big_smile: I guess you could probably find an unofficial LineageOS ROM for your device on XDA ( https://forum.xda-developers.com/kindle-fire-hd/7-development )